# JavaScript separate file in script src tag detecting but not working

Tags: javascript, tomcat, intellij-idea, src

I am learning JS basics and trying to separate my js code from html file.
Looks like IDEA detects .js file correctly, but after launching - alert doesn't pop up.
If alert() is inside the script tag (without separate .js file) - everything works fine.

This is an educational project based on Java and TomCat server, so maybe the problem is there.
Can someone help?

My HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>RPG</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/my.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>RPG admin panel</h1>
<script src="app.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js file:

alert(1);

Screenshot of project hierarchy:
[hierarcgy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCd43.png)

Idea file detection:
[file detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClVF6.png)

**UPD**:
Try 1
[differnet source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4iAB.png)

**UPD 2**
Found an error. Still no solution.
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvix6.png)
[detailed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEHg1.png)

Comment: Use relative paths: `./` for current dir. `./../` for previous dir. `./../../` for the dir before that etc. Your webserver may consider just `/` to be the document root and not the current dir. So `./css/my.css` and `./app.js`

Comment: Tried this way. Didn't help. Added a screenshot to a post

Comment: Open your browser and press F12. This will open up your browser console. Then load your website. The console will show you an error in the form that it can't get the File you're trying to load. The error will also show you where it's trying to load the file from. Show a screenshot of that console if you can't figure it out yourself from there on out

Comment: ./app.js didn't work?

Comment: Does the alert appear if you use "Open in browser" functionality (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/editing-html-files.html#ws_html_preview_output_procedure)?

Comment: @icecub Found an error in console. It really doesn't load my app.js file, but it shows the name of the file in a folder tree. I uploaded screenshot in post

Comment: @JarneKompier nope.. Nothing I tried with directories didn't work..

Comment: @Oksana I am using IDEA with TomCat, so I don't have Open in browser option.